# Struct Debugging

Tags: c, debugging, struct, compiler-errors

I hope this is allowed, as I don't have a specific question other than why this doesn't run. I need some help with the debugging because I can't figure this out. I modeled this off of a similar struct I'd done before and just added in what was needed and changed the names and stuff. Can't figure out why this one doesn't run and the other does. If you'd like to see the one I based it on, just ask and I can edit this and add it. Anyway, here's the code of the one that won't run:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int player_data(){
    struct player_info create_player(void);
    struct player_info{
    char name[30];
    int Level, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha;
    };



    struct player_info create_player(void);{
    struct player_info aPlayer;
    {
    char c;
    int i;
    printf("Enter Player Name: ");
    scanf("%s",aPlayer.name);
    i = strlen(aPlayer.name);
    do{
        scanf("%c", &c);
        aPlayer.name[i++] = c;
    }
    while (c != '\n');
    aPlayer.name[i - 1] = 0;
    }
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&aPlayer.name);

    printf("Level: ");
    scanf("%d",aPlayer.Level);

    printf("Strength Modifier: ");
    scanf("%d",aPlayer.Str);

    printf("Dexterity Modifier: ");
    scanf("%d", aPlayer.Dex);

    printf("Constitution Modifier: ");
    scanf("%d", aPlayer.Con);

    printf("Intelligence Modifier: ");
    scanf("%d", aPlayer.Int);

    printf("Wisdom Modifier: ");
    scanf("%d", aPlayer.Wis);

    printf("Charisma Modifier: ");
    scanf("%d", aPlayer.Cha);
    return aPlayer;
};
}

int save_data(){
             FILE* PlayerFile = fopen("players.txt","w");
             int i = 0;

             for (i = 0; i < 1; i++){
             struct player_info aPlayer = create_player();
             fprintf(PlayerFile, "%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", aPlayer.name, aPlayer.Level, aPlayer.Str, aPlayer.Dex, aPlayer.Con, aPlayer.Int, aPlayer.Wis, aPlayer.Cha);
             }
             fclose(PlayerFile);
             return 0;
             }

int main(){
    char enter = 0;
    int n, i, response;
    printf("\nEnter 8 to add player data.");
    if(response == 8){
            player_data();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

And here are my compiler errors:

```
save_player.c: In function 'player_data':
save_player.c:53:9: error: incompatible types when returning type 'struct player_info' but 'int' was expected
  return aPlayer;
         ^
save_player.c: In function 'save_data':
save_player.c:62:21: error: variable 'aPlayer' has initializer but incomplete type
              struct player_info aPlayer = create_player();
                     ^
save_player.c:62:43: warning: implicit declaration of function 'create_player' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              struct player_info aPlayer = create_player();
                                           ^
save_player.c:15:21: note: previous declaration of 'create_player' was here
  struct player_info create_player(void);{
                     ^
save_player.c:62:43: error: incompatible implicit declaration of function 'create_player'
              struct player_info aPlayer = create_player();
                                           ^
save_player.c:15:21: note: previous implicit declaration of 'create_player' was here
  struct player_info create_player(void);{
                     ^
save_player.c:62:33: error: storage size of 'aPlayer' isn't known
              struct player_info aPlayer = create_player();
```

Comment: You don't need help with debugging just yet. You need help with basic C syntax and code formatting. Struct definitions go outside of functions. Functions don't nest. You indent each block 4 spaces to the right. This kind of stuff.

Comment: *sigh. Wow. That makes me feel dumb. Removed the function and that cleared up all but one error, so. I guess we all need a little nudge sometimes. Thanks for this.